# Play virtual surrounding sound without a usual speaker (with a single device)

Tags: audio

I would like to know whether is it possible to play sound without a usual speaker. My requirement is...
1. I want to simulate the same experience of surrounding system without the usual speaker
2. My expected device is a single device, it could simulate the sorrounding effect

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think FeONIC devices are doing the same thing.

pls refer the wikipedia link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FeONIC